# Log4j not logging with JBoss 6.1

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

I have a JavaEE application and I am deploying it on JBoss 6.1. I wanna use Log4j.

These are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} %5p: %c{2} - %m%n
```

I have added this line on the standalone.conf

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"
```

This is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-deployment-structure>
 <deployment>
  <exclusions>
    <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
    <module name="org.slf4j" />
    <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
  </exclusions>   
 </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I can see no logs on my console. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `$JAVA_OPTS` is not overridden somewhere (to test it you could put it directly in the `standalone.sh` script just before the initialization.

If the problem still persist, then add the `-Dlog4j.configuration` property to specify the path to the configuration log file (make sure you have the right permission).

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false -Dlog4j.configuration=file:$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/log4j.xml"
```

Make sure you [configure the `log4j.xml` file](https://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html).

Note that even if you define the properties in the `.conf` file, they will be interpreted in the `.sh` file so they must be in valid shell format which mean a space after an `=` for example could be the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds promising. I'll try when I'm back from my vacation next week, hope thats OK for the bounty

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link.http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-log/jboss-log4j-configuration I hope this will help u

Comment: This answer might fit the community edition of jboss, but not the enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

as you are using slf4j-log4j12 , we should configure for slf4j-log4j12 also, add following in logge properties.

```
 log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT
 log4j.logger.deng=INFO
 log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
 log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```